# E: Type 'cdrom://Ubuntu' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt

I ran `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal and got this response:

```
E: Type 'cdrom://Ubuntu' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: pls help and stranded here

Comment: can you post the contents of your sources.list file?

Comment: pls how will i do that?

Comment: did you check the CD-ROM option in the "Software & Updates" control panel? if yes, then disabe it and type again `sudo apt update`

Comment: no i didnt check it

Comment: i also received an info that ubuntu 16.04 has experienced  an internal error

Comment: that "internal error" is common in ubuntu, could you please post you /etc/apt/sources.list file?

Comment: you can see your file content by typing `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2) xenial Release

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted multiverse universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted multiverse universe

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem not so familiar with usage of terminal or any text editors you could just type in this command.

```
sudo sed -i 's/cdrom/#cdrom/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This comments out your installation CD from your default repositories.

Comment: E: Malformed line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
same thing

Comment: Would be much easier if you just post us your `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` output.

Comment: #cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2) xenial Release

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted multiverse universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restriction

Comment: that seems not to be the full file, can you edit your question with the output formatted since it's kinda hard to read like that.

Comment: i cant paste all the output in my cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there.